# How can I write this query for an exact value with a multi foreign key table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

```
 table_1:

   id                 
   1       
   2

 table_2:

   id   table2_order
   1        1
   2        1
   2        2 

table_3:

 id     table2_order     order     code
 1          1              1        52   
 1          1              2        52
 2          1              1        69
 2          1              2        52
 2          2              1        01
```

To join these tables this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id AND t2.table2_order = t3.table2_order
WHERE t3.code = '52'
```

How can I get all values that are 52 and not 69 also?
They are searching for the value 52. So they need ids with only code 52. 
And they can search one to many of the codes. Needs to be exactly codes only.
Here I want to get id = 1 but not id = 2 because it has 69.

Comment: After your edits looks like you need inner join, not left. And check if number of `52` rows is equal to number of all rows for that ID. Like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=440df99faddcb8680a39912421d160e4). But this is not clear: _they can search for one-to-many codes_. Perhaps `code in (52, 53, 54)`?

Comment: he wants rows that have 52 but there are no other rows that contains a value other than 52

Comment: ^^^ exactly yea

Comment: @Hogan - this is clear. Your query returns row for id=2 and order=2. Which has no code=52.

Answer (score 1):

Has 52 only

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id AND t2.table2_order = t3.table2_order and t3.code = '52'
LEFT JOIN table_3 no ON t2.id = no.id AND t2.table2_order = no.table2_order and no.code <> '52'
WHERE no.id is null
```

This is called an anti-join. It means you only get results for IDs which have `code = 52` and don't have `code != 52`.

Comment: @dropkick -- this is solving your problem based on the example code that you gave.  assuming your code is correct then this will get the items that have code = 52 and only 52.  using a left join and then checking for null finds all items where they did not join ---this allows you to exclude based on the join criteria.

Comment: @APC How can I make a better table structure? I was hoping the query I have below would explain how the joins are suppose to be.

Comment: @Hogan table_3 order is the unique identifier for the table.

Comment: I have changed the posted code so that both instances of `table_3` join to `table_2`. This fixes the typo that @dropkick complained of, and I think is more expressive of intent too.

Comment: Edited the order for table_2

Comment: @APC -- I see the change you made -- which does not change the functionality (JOINS are associative) but if written like this is clearer :shrug: